# How to modify the RowSideColor column size in R's heatmap.2()

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I have the following data:

```
    foo_06.ix   bar_06.ix   bar_06.iz   qux_06.ix   qux_06.iz
1416474_at Igdcc4   0.563   5.649   1.654   0.776   0.973
1416576_at Socs3    5.793   5.417   0.694   3.256   0.951
...
```

Which I want to plot the hierarchical clustering heat map.

With this code:

```
library(gplots);
library(RColorBrewer);

tm <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1494806/plain/",header=TRUE,sep="\t")

nofclust <- 21;
# Clustering functions 
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="euclidean")

d.tm <- distfunc(tm)
fit.tm <- hclustfunc(d.tm)
clusters <- cutree(fit.tm, k=nofclust)

# Define colours
hmcols <- rev(brewer.pal(11,"Spectral"));
selcol <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(12,"Set3"))
selcol2 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Set1"))
sdcol= selcol(5);
clustcol = selcol2(nofclust);

# Plot heatmap
pdf(file="tmp.pdf",width=27,height=27);
heatmap.2(as.matrix(tm),dendrogram="row",scale="row",RowSideColors=clustcol[clusters],ColSideColors=sdcol,col=hmcols,trace="none", margin=c(12,12), hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc,lwid=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1),keysize=0.5);
dev.off()
```

It produces the following figure:
[image]

Using the fixed PDF size (27x27) what I want to do:

1. Create the heatmap where the `row side column` is smaller than all
   5 primary columns. Currently it's too wide.
   These 5 primary column size I fixed with `lwid=0.1`, so do not change.
2. Squeeze the dendogram.
3. If the above two takes effect, the  row names on the right takes prominent space in the page.

How can I modify my code above to achieve these?

Comment: How did you solve it?